# The meaning of "scare half the country"

Tags: meaning

‘‘I didn’t much know, and I didn’t much care what was going on. The row of that trooper falling ought to have **scared half the country**, and I would take my oath that we were being stalked by a full regiment in the rear, and they were making row enough to rouse all Afghanistan. I sat tight, but nothing happened.’
This is from 'Lost Region' by Rudyard Kipling.
http://www.telelib.com/authors/K/KiplingRudyard/prose/ManyInventions/lostlegion.html

I don't understand the meaning of "scared half the country"

I am glad if someone would kindly teach me.

Comment: It is still "Lost **L**egion" not **R**egion.  A legion is a division of an army. A region is a district of a country.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of [**hyperbole**](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exaggeration).

When taken literally, the phrase is easy to understand: The row (noise) of the trooper falling over was so loud that the speaker expected *half of everyone in the country* to have been scared by it. But this does not make sense; it is an exaggeration. Really all they mean is "the noise was very loud."

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I clearly understand the meaning of  "scare half the country."